# show un-approved comments at wordpress front end

Tags: comments

I've almost finished coding up a function that allows **contributers** when they are the post author to manage comments left on their own post (portfolio) couldnt find a plugin to do it so had to get myself dirty.

It will basically work like this:

1) User leaves a comment on post_authors portfolio.

2) Post_author is notified by email that they have a comment for moderation (this bit is handled by a plugin "notify-on-comments").

3) Post_author logs in and goes to his/her portfolio page and in the comments are two links one for "delete" and one for "approve" comment.

Now i can get the delete to work on **already published comments**, my problem is that i am wanting to **show the unpublished comment along with the published comments** (dont want folks having access to wp-admin dashboard to moderate comments, i want it all done on the front end),

Does anyone know how i can do this part of showing the un-approved comment at front-end to contributers?

Once completed i will be more than happy to share the code and credits should anyone else need it.

Regards and thanks in advance

Comment: Just add 'edit_published_posts' capability to the user role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy:

```
function show_portfolio_comments( $post_ID ) 
{
    // NOT approved
    $comments_unapproved = get_comments( array( 'status' => 'hold', 'post_id' => $post_ID ) );
    foreach ( $comments_unapproved as $comments) 
    {
      if ( current_user_can( 'edit_published_posts' ) // maybe you'll have to switch to some other cap 
      {
      ?>
      <div class="comment">
         <h4>Unapproved Comments on your portfolio</h4>
         <div class="comment-author"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></div>
         <div class="comment-content"><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></div>
      </div>
      <?php
      } // endif; - current_user_can( 'edit_published_posts' )
    }

    // ALREADY approved
    $comments_approved = get_comments( array( 'status' => 'approve', 'post_id' => $post_ID ) );
    foreach ( $comments_approved as $comments) 
    {
      ?>
      <div class="comment">
      <?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_published_post' ) { ?>
         <h4>Approved Comments on your portfolio</h4>
      <?php }  // endif; - current_user_can( 'edit_published_posts' ) ?>
         <div class="comment-author"><?php echo $comment->comment_author; ?></div>
         <div class="comment-content"><?php echo $comment->comment_content; ?></div>
      </div>
      <?php
    }
}
```

Template Tag:

```
// Use it in your template like this & don't forget to push the post ID into it:
$post_ID = $GLOBALS['post']->ID;
// or:
global $post;
$post_ID = $post->ID;
// or:
$post_ID = get_the_ID();
// or:
$post_ID = get_queried_object_id();

show_portfolio_comments( $post_ID );
```

Comment: Hi there @Kaiser, thanks for taking the time out with this code, i can see from what you have done that it does what i require. The only issue is that i cannot get the code to run without erroring, i have used a portion of the code and it worked perfectly, but when i use the code either whole or just the **un-approved** portion i have an issue with the curly braces, i tried allsorts to get it to work but it wont have it. A good point you made about the "capability" in my case it needs to be **edit_published_posts**

Comment: @Martin: Glad it worked... so far, but you could be a little more specific: what error message and what about the curly braces? what did you try and how? Just update your answer, so i can take a look.

Comment: all is good now, the problem was the 2 if statements were both missing a closing bracket, which for the life of me i missed for ages. At this point now everything is working at 99% the problem im having is all unapproved comments are showing on all posts rather than on the post they are assigned to, so im summizing i need to find a way to fix these by post_id, many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Martin: See the updated answer. There where no missing closing curly brackets (marked them with a comment). I also updated the capability and the `$post->ID`. It should work as you'd expect. I also wrapped it into a function, that you can use as template tag. Just place the function into your `functions.php` file.